# A conjugacy class of an element in a profinite group is either finite or uncountably infinite?

Tags: group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $g$ be an element of a profinite group $G$. **Is it true that the conjugacy class $g^G=\{hgh^{-1}~|~h\in G\}$ of $g$ in $G$ is finite or uncountably infinite?**

I know that profinite groups are always finite or uncountable, and we can consider the coset space $G/C_G(g)$ where $C_G(g)$ is the centralizer of $g$ in $G$. Thus, we are done if $C_G(g)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. What if $C_G(g)$ is not normal? Any comments and references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coset space is always a homogeneous compact Hausdorff space even if it is not a group, and that is enough to conclude it is either finite or uncountable.  If it is not discrete, then by homogeneity it has no isolated points, and a nonempty compact Hausdorff space with no isolated points is uncountable.